# How to set up the date information filter for a specific user?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two filters and they do not work exactly as they should. Firstly, after a particular user has been selected from the list, all the information on this user for all dates is displayed in the notes, although a certain date is set on which nothing should be output so as there is empty. And secondly, if I start changing the date in select, then all the information for all users starts to be displayed although a certain user was originally selected. Below I gave the code for these filters. How can I fix this? Tell me please.

```
  selectedUser = null;
  users: Array<User>;
  notes: Array<Note>;
  years: Array<Year>;
  filteredNotes = [];




//Filter datas for the selected user
SelectedUser(userId) {
  this.selectedUser = this.users.find(el => {
    return el.user_id === userId
  });
  this.filteredNotes = this.notes.filter((note) => note.n_users_id == this.selectedUser.user_id);
}

//Filter data by date selection from the list

onYearSelection(year){
    this.filteredNotes = []
    this.filteredNotes = this.notes.filter(note => note.years  == year);
}
```

That is, how can I combine these operations. So that I chose the user chose the date I wanted and displayed all the available information on this user and the selected date.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.filteredNotes = this.notes.filter(proj => years.indexOf(proj.year)!= -1)
```

and with ES6, you can use Array.includes

```
this.years.includes(proj.year)
```

Comment: it should just add a console log and debug